# Mongoose Plugins nestjs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-plugins, nestjs

How can I implement the mongoose plugin using nestjs?

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';
import mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate';
import mongoose_delete from 'mongoose-delete';

const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, 'El nombre de usuario es requerido']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'La clave es requerida'],
        select: false
    }
});

UsuarioSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: '{PATH} debe ser único' });
UsuarioSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
UsuarioSchema.plugin(mongoose_delete, { deletedAt : true, deletedBy : true, overrideMethods: true });
```

Error: First param to `schema.plugin()` must be a function, got "undefined"

Answer (score 19):

This is a snippet for those who are using [mongoose-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate) plugin with nestjs. You can also install [@types/mongoose-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongoose-paginate) for getting the typings support

1. Code for adding the paginate plugin to the schema:

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import * as mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate';

export const MessageSchema = new Schema({
// Your schema definitions here
});

// Register plugin with the schema
MessageSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
```

2. Now in the Message interface document

```
export interface Message extends Document {
// Your schema fields here
}
```

3. Now you can easily get the paginate method inside the service class like so

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { PaginateModel } from 'mongoose';
import { Message } from './interfaces/message.interface';

@Injectable()
export class MessagesService {
    constructor(
        // The 'PaginateModel' will provide the necessary pagination methods
        @InjectModel('Message') private readonly messageModel: PaginateModel<Message>,
    ) {}

    /**
     * Find all messages in a channel
     *
     * @param {string} channelId
     * @param {number} [page=1]
     * @param {number} [limit=10]
     * @returns
     * @memberof MessagesService
     */
    async findAllByChannelIdPaginated(channelId: string, page: number = 1, limit: number = 10) {
        const options = {
            populate: [
                // Your foreign key fields to populate
            ],
            page: Number(page),
            limit: Number(limit),
        };
        // Get the data from database
        return await this.messageModel.paginate({ channel: channelId }, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I have this error, but working fine => Property 'paginate' does not exist on type 'Model<User, {}>'.ts(2339)

Comment: That's because I used Model instead of PaginateModel inside constructor. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I need the same but with __mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2__, this example doesn't works and doesn't exist @types. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi @Hector sorry, i am not familiar with that plugin. Probably you can look at the source code for the same and create your own typings file and use it in your project internally. Don't really have to depend on external typings always.

Comment: @SandeepKNair can you show your `message.provider.ts`?  I am unsure how you're satisfying the `@Inject('Message')` Thanks!

Comment: @AdamCox there isn't any difference in how `Message` is injected to the module provider section. 
```typescript
imports: [
MongooseModule.forFeature([
            { name: 'Message', schema: MessageSchema },
        ])
]
```

Comment: @SandeepKNair thanks. I am working on similar but using what Hector mentioned.. SO ques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65669164/how-to-provide-server-side-pagination-with-nestjs

Comment: @AdamCox sorry I thought you were asking about `mongoose-paginate-v2`. I haven't used `mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2` plugin personally on any projects yet. But ideally there would be a wrapper interface type for aggregate-paginate plugin like `PaginateModel` in mongoose-paginate if I am not wrong. You will have to find it in the @types that you installed `@types/mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2` as npm dependency.

Answer (score 3):

NestJS Documentation has better way to add plugins to either individual schema.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
      {
        name: Cat.name,
        useFactory: () => {
          const schema = CatsSchema;
          schema.plugin(require('mongoose-autopopulate'));
          return schema;
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Or if at global level.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/test', {
      connectionFactory: (connection) => {
        connection.plugin(require('mongoose-autopopulate'));
        return connection;
      }
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This is great. But curious how to add it in if using this Mongooge import format `MongooseModule.forRootAsync({useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({uri: "blah", user: "blah", pass: "blah"}), inject: [ConfigService] });`

Comment: @wongz check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75739750/10806551

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';
import * as mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate';
import * as mongoose_delete from 'mongoose-delete';

const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, 'El nombre de usuario es requerido']
   },
   password: {
       type: String,
       required: [true, 'La clave es requerida'],
       select: false
   }
});

UsuarioSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: '{PATH} debe ser único' });
UsuarioSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
UsuarioSchema.plugin(mongoose_delete, { deletedAt : true, deletedBy : true, overrideMethods: true });

export default UsuarioSchema;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
import UsuarioSchema from './UsuarioSchema'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using forRootAsync, This worked for me as below

```
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
  useFactory: async (ConfigService: ConfigService) => {
    const connectionName: string =
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? 'DATABASE_URL'
        : 'LOCAL_DATABASE_URL';

    mongoose.plugin(require('mongoose-unique-validator')); // import mongoose the normal way and you can import your plugin as desired
    return {
      uri: ConfigService.get<string>(connectionName),
    };
  },
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of using `timestamp` plugin

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import * as timestamp from 'mongoose-timestamp';
export const ConversationSchema = new Schema({
  users: [String],
}).plugin(timestamp);
```

try replace

```
import uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';
import mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate';
import mongoose_delete from 'mongoose-delete';
```

by

```
import * as uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';
import * as mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate';
import * as mongoose_delete from 'mongoose-delete';
```

Answer (score -1):

If you followed the official doc, you can add plugins in this file:

```
`export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'DbConnectionToken',
    useFactory: async () => {
      (mongoose as any).Promise = global.Promise;

      mongoose
        .plugin('pluginOne')
        .plugin('pluginTwo')

      return await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nest', {
        useMongoClient: true,
      });
    },
  },
];`
```

Remind, If you set the plugins in the Schema file, you set the same plugins as many times. The best way to set plugins is only once.

Comment: Can you explain how you use this `databaseProviders` and where?