# How to provide server-side pagination with NestJS?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

Given a MEVN stack using Nestjs, MongoDB(mongoose) I am working to setup server-side pagination. My approach is to use the mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2, but I have not been able to distill what I need from my research<sup>1</sup> to make this work within the framework of Nestjs(typescript) and mongoose. Thanks for the assist..

Following documentation on [Nestjs mongoose models](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/mongodb#model-injection), and [mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2 setup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2), I have the following:

`contact.provider.ts`

```
import mongoose, { Connection, AggregatePaginateResult, model } from "mongoose";
import { ContactSchema } from "./contact.schema";
import aggregatePaginate from "mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2";
import { IContact } from "./interfaces/contact.interface";

// notice plugin setup:
ContactSchema.plugin(aggregatePaginate);

// is this correct ?
interface ContactModel<T extends Document> extends AggregatePaginateResult<T> {}

// how to create model for factory use ?
export const ContactModel: ContactModel<any> = model<IContact>('Contact', ContactSchema) as ContactModel<IContact>;

export const contactProvider = [
  {
    provide: 'CONTACT_MODEL',
    useFactory: (connection: Connection) => {
      // how to instantiate model ?
      let model = connection.model<ContactModel<any>>('Contact', ContactSchema);
      return model;
    },
    inject: ['DATABASE_CONNECTION'],
  },
];
```

I am between reading the Nestjs documentation, mongoose documentation, and typescript documentation. Somewhere along this path there is a way to provide the aggregatePaginate method on my Contact model, so that I can call like:

`contact.service.ts`

```
// Set up the aggregation
const myAggregate = this.contactModel.aggregate(aggregate_options);
const result = await this.contactModel.aggregatePaginate(myAggregate, options); // aggregatePaginate does not exist!
```

Review code in progress - available on [this branch](https://github.com/abcox/toybox-api/tree/server-side-pagination).

Research

1. [Mongoose the Typescript way…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482136/mongoose-the-typescript-way)
2. [Complete Guide for using Typescript in Mongoose with lean() function](https://jasonching2005.medium.com/complete-guide-for-using-typescript-in-mongoose-with-lean-function-e55adf1189dc)
3. [Complete guide for Typescript with Mongoose for Node.js](https://medium.com/@agentwhs/complete-guide-for-typescript-for-mongoose-for-node-js-8cc0a7e470c1)
4. [MosesEsan/mesan-nodejs-crud-api-with-pagination-filtering-grouping-and-sorting-capabilities](https://github.com/MosesEsan/mesan-nodejs-crud-api-with-pagination-filtering-grouping-and-sorting-capabilities/blob/master/src/controllers/event.js)
5. [Node.js API: Add CRUD Operations With Pagination, Filtering, Grouping, and Sorting Capabilities.](https://medium.com/swlh/node-js-api-add-crud-operations-with-pagination-filtering-grouping-and-sorting-capabilities-55375ad0b774)
6. [API Paging Built The Right Way](https://www.mixmax.com/engineering/api-paging-built-the-right-way/)
7. [SO: Mongoose Plugins nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387454/mongoose-plugins-nestjs)
8. [SO: Pagination with mongoose and nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889678/pagination-with-mongoose-and-nestjs)

Comment: Same here, it looks there is an open issue in Github about this in case you want to track it:  https://github.com/aravindnc/mongoose-paginate-v2/issues/121

Answer (score 4):

There is a conflict between NestJs and ***mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2*** and ***mongoose-paginate-v2*** because those plugins are using  @types/mongoose, so, NestJS has conflicts if you use ***@types/mongoose***.

I tell you this because i was trying the same thing and figure it out that is not posible to implement mongoo-aggreate-paginate-v2/mongoose-paginate-v2 till Nestjs solve the issues with @types/mongoose.

I can recommend you make a custom function by your own to do that or use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate because that plugin does not require @types/mongoose.

Comment: Thanks. This is on the shelf atm, and I will circle back to it and provide my feedback when I do. Thanks again!

Comment: @AdamCox was you able to use mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2 on nestjs? By now,  mongoose-paginate-v2 works well, but the aggregate I cant make it work.

Comment: @Sumuel check my GitHub repo for latest.  I think I did progress a little on this, but it's on the shelf again.  Writing some react-native+TS mob app. (the woes of TS nav!)...